# Does Python's main thread get garbage collected when it stops?

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-multithreading

In a multi-threaded Python process I have a number of *non-daemon* threads, by which I mean threads which keep the main process alive even after the main thread has exited / stopped.

My non-daemon threads hold [weak references](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref) to certain objects in the main thread, but when the main thread ends (control falls off the bottom of the file) these objects do *not* appear to be garbage collected, and my weak reference finaliser callbacks don't fire.

Am I wrong to expect the main thread to be garbage collected? I would have expected that the thread-locals would be deallocated (i.e. garbage collected)...

What have I missed?

---

**Supporting materials**

Output from `pprint.pprint( threading.enumerate() )` showing the main thread has stopped while others soldier on.

```
[<_MainThread(MainThread, stopped 139664516818688)>,
 <LDQServer(testLogIOWorkerThread, started 139664479889152)>,
 <_Timer(Thread-18, started 139663928870656)>,
 <LDQServer(debugLogIOWorkerThread, started 139664437925632)>,
 <_Timer(Thread-17, started 139664463103744)>,
 <_Timer(Thread-19, started 139663937263360)>,
 <LDQServer(testLogIOWorkerThread, started 139664471496448)>,
 <LDQServer(debugLogIOWorkerThread, started 139664446318336)>]
```

And since someone always asks about the use-case...

My network service occasionally misses its real-time deadlines (which causes a total system failure in the worst case). This turned out to be because logging of (important) DEBUG data would block whenever the file-system has a tantrum. So I am attempting to retrofit a number of established specialised logging libraries to defer blocking I/O to a worker thread.

Sadly the established usage pattern is a mix of short-lived logging channels which log overlapping parallel transactions, and long-lived module-scope channels which are never explicitly closed.

So I created a decorator which defers method calls to a worker thread. The worker thread is non-daemon to ensure that all (slow) blocking I/O completes before the interpreter exits, and holds a weak reference to the client-side (where method calls get enqueued). When the client-side is garbage collected the weak reference's callback fires and the worker thread knows no more work will be enqueued, and so will exit at its next convenience.

This seems to work fine in all but one important use-case: when the logging channel is in the main thread. When the main thread stops / exits the logging channel is *not* finalised, and so my (non-daemon) worker thread lives on keeping the entire process alive.

Comment: There's a lot of assuming that will have to go into answering this without having some concrete code example... That said, have you tried explicitly closing/deleting the logging channel at the end of the main thread, just to see whether the weak reference's callback gets fired then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad idea for your main thread to end without calling `join` on all non-daemon threads, or to make any assumptions about what happens if you don't.

---

If you don't do anything very unusual, CPython (at least [2.0](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.0/Lib/threading.py#l457)-[3.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/threading.py#l829)) will cover for you by automatically calling `join` on all non-daemon threads as pair of `_MainThread._exitfunc`. This isn't actually documented, so you shouldn't rely on it, but it's what's happening to you.

Your main thread hasn't actually exited at all; it's blocking inside its `_MainThread._exitfunc` trying to `join` some arbitrary non-daemon thread. Its objects won't be finalized until the `atexit` handler is called, which doesn't happen until after it finishes joining all non-daemon threads.

---

Meanwhile, if you avoid this (e.g., by using `thread`/`_thread` directly, or by detaching the main thread from its object or forcing it into a normal `Thread` instance), what happens? It isn't defined. The `threading` module makes no reference to it at all, but in CPython 2.0-3.3, and likely in any other reasonable implementation, it falls to the [`thread`/`_thread` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#module-thread) to decide. And, as the docs say:

> When the main thread exits, it is system defined whether the other threads survive. On SGI IRIX using the native thread implementation, they survive. On most other systems, they are killed without executing try ... finally clauses or executing object destructors.

So, if you manage to avoid `join`ing all of your non-daemon threads, you have to write code that can handle both having them hard-killed like daemon threads, and having them continue running until exit.

If they do continue running, at least in CPython 2.7 and 3.3 on POSIX systems, that the main thread's OS-level thread handle, and various higher-level Python objects representing it, may be still retained, and not get cleaned up by the GC.

---

On top of that, even if everything were released, you can't rely on the GC ever deleting anything. If your code depends on deterministic GC, there are many cases you can get away with it in CPython (although your code will then break in PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc.), but at exit time is not one of them. CPython can, and will, leak objects at exit time and let the OS sort 'em out. (This is why writable files that you never close may lose the last few writes—the `__del__` method never gets called, and therefore there's nobody to tell them to `flush`, and at least on POSIX the underlying `FILE*` doesn't automatically flush either.)

If you want something to be cleaned up when the main thread finishes, you have to use some kind of `close` function rather than relying on `__del__`, and you have to make sure it gets triggered via a `with` block around the main block of code, an `atexit` function, or some other mechanism.

---

One last thing:

> I would have expected that the thread-locals would be deallocated (i.e. garbage collected)...

Do you actually have thread locals somewhere? Or do you just mean locals and/or globals that are only accessed in one thread?

Comment: As it happens, I meant locals and/or globals that are only accessed in one thread. I will try using the thread's local attribute just to see what it does.

Comment: I've never heard about the illegality of the main thread ending without calling join() before - can you refer me to some documentation on that? I find myself wondering what the point in a non-daemon thread is if you have to join it any way (surely such usage makes the thread indistinguishable from a daemon thread?)

Comment: @RobM: I think you may have things backward. The point of daemon thread is that you _don't_ join them; you just leave them running, and they gets abruptly killed when all non-daemon threads exit. The point of non-daemon threads is that you can and do join them.

Comment: @RobM: As for the requirement to call `join`… it's not as clear as I stated in the initial version. I've updated the answer to give all the details. But the short version is that it would be very hard to write correct code that _didn't_ `join` all non-daemon threads, and the only reason you think you're getting away with it is that `threading` is doing the `join`s for you behind your back.